# Если ничего не передаем в intent выводить "ничего не добавлено" Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!
Возможно легкий вопрос, но информации так и не нашла... Нужна ваша помощь...

**Приложение:** У меня есть список товаров, которые добавляются в корзину при нажатии кнопки "Добавить", а снизу есть кнопка корзина, при нажатии которой я перехожу в активити Корзины с добавленными продуктами.

**Реализация:** Есть класс *Product* (с описанием товаров), *Main* (где выводится весь список), *Cart* (куда падуют товары), и два адаптера *AdapterBox* (который собирает все продукты и в котором прописан метод клик для кнопки, при нажатии которой товар добавляется в Cart) и *AdapterCart* (для визуализации добавленных продуктов).

Мой AdapterCart:

```
// кол-во элементов
@Override
public int getCount() {return objects.size();}
// товар по позиции
Product getProduct ( int position){return ((Product) getItem(position));}
```

Прием и добавление продукта в Cart в список ListView:

```
cartAdapter = new AdapterCart(this, products);
//Передаем продукт
Product obj = (Product) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Product");
products.add(obj);
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvcart);
lvMain.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
```

**Вопрос.** Если я не нажимаю кнопку добавить у товара и сразу перехожу в корзину выдается ошибка, поскольку там прописан код по принятию товара. Как написать условие, если кол-во товаров "ноль", то в Корзине появляется надпись "А ну ка купи уже что-нибудь".

Логично я понимаю, что должен быть счетчик добавленных продуктов, и он должен быть в AdapterCart, но как его реализовать и прописать не понимаю...
Вот такое не канает и выделяет красным скобку 
    int size = cartAdapter.getProduct().getCount();

Comment: СПАСИБО ЗА ПОДСКАЗКУ!!!! Прописала условие `if (getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Product") == null) { show="ничего не добавлено"` и заработало, я думала будет все сложнее

Comment: Если использовать `ListActivity` или `ListFragment`, то в них реализован механизм подмены списка, когда он пуст.

Comment: @pavlofff как вам ставить благодарность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно сделать проверку, что через `Intent` в `Activity` не передали никакие данные, просто проверьте его на `null`:

```
if (getIntent() == null){
     // действия при отсутствии полученных данных
}
```

PS: получать значение из пустого интента - лишнее действие, то есть дополнительный запрос `getParcelableExtra("Product")` не нужен

Comment: Если прописать просто то при нажатии на корзину, приложение вылетает c ошибкой. Возможно мой где-то косяк, могу в вопросе написать что выдает монитор.

Comment: столкнулась с проблемой, если сначала набирать товары, а потом жать корзину, то выдает ошибку... Я правильно понимаю логику, что тут механизм работы следующий- нажал кнопку объект попадает в массив, потом в корзину, массив распаковываем? Я хотела сделать проще, нажал кнопку товар сразу летит в корзину и там распаковывается без массива... Можно моим способом реализовать?

Comment: задайте вопрос по этой проблеме, где изложите ее подробно. в комментарии слишком мало подробностей, чтобы можно было ответить определенно

Comment: в любом случае все рабочие решения такого функционала связаны с использованием БД. На динамических списках это костыльные и малопрдуктивные способы, требующие решать проблемы, которых быть в принципе не должно. В частности вы не можете передавать в другую активити динамические данные, пока эта активити не находится на экране